Difference between returning a Javascript expression or a React fragment with a child with the same expression
Is there a difference between
const Component = (props)=>{... return (JS_EXPRESSION)}

and
const Component = (props)=>{... return <>{JS_EXPRESSION}</>}

More specifically, I got a lot of cases where JS_EXPRESSION is a ternary operation
mainly
JS_EXPRESSION= condition? <Component1/>: <Component2/>

Is there any difference between the two?
For examples in terms of mounting and unmounting?

There's no difference practically speaking. The Fragment is unnecessary but there won't be any effective difference in mounting/unmounting of your two demo components

No, there are is no difference between those, to quote the official docs:

Grouping elements in Fragment has no effect on the resulting DOM;

and thus also no impact on (un)mounting the component.

You could however just return the ternary operator itself to reduce the code:
const Component = (props)=> condition ? <Component1/> : <Component2/>;

